# What would be an event to use with a Maya scriptJob command so it tracks when an object is added or removed froma render layer?

Tags: python, maya

I have a script that needs to update its GUI when an object is added or removed from a render layer. Right now, I can not find an event to trigger the GUI update using a scriptJob. What would be a good event to use?

Comment: the event renderLayerManagerChange isnt working for you ? If you are using pqyt/pyside you might be able to change the hover event of the window to update. Otherwise create a button 'refresh', it is simple but works fine :D

Comment: im using that one, but it does not seem to trigger when objects are added or removed from a render layer using the command: editRenderLayerMembers.

Comment: Im using pyside2. can you explain more about a button refresh?

Comment: just put a button refresh to refresh your gui manually

Comment: oh i see, well the trick is, the GUIi would ideally update when the user is adding and removing objects with other tools in Maya. id like my script to dynamically follow along. it catches up as soon as a selection changes or they change layers, but there is a moment where its behind if they only add/remove an object.

Comment: yeah i understand the point maybe you should intergrate in your ui the editing layer part or even the whole renderLayer management. Otherwise you might be able to catch the "connectionChange" event